# Java method with unlimited arguments

Tags: java, methods, arguments

The Spring framework uses methods where you can pass as many arguments as you like.

I would like to write a function that can also take an unlimited amount of data. How is this feature called so that I can read about it? Or how can I define it?

Comment: which class has that method? Maybe is like static main(String[] args)

Comment: Define "unlimited amount of data".

Answer (score 172, accepted):

It's called [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html).

It allows a method to take any number of arguments. They are accessible as an array in the method:

```
public void foo(String... args) {
    for (String arg : args) {
      // do smth with arg.
     }
}
```

This is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). The compiler hides the array creation, so instead of

```
 bar.foo(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"});
```

you write

```
 bar.foo("1", "2", "3");
```

Comment: Your first link is no longer working. Current link is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html

Comment: private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

public void addProduct(Product... args){
        products.add(args);
    }

This gives an error "List cannot be applied"

I want the method to take an unlimited amount of arguments I.E 

cart.addProduct(toothbrush, shampoo...)

Answer (score 16):

To add the Bozho's answer, you can also have other arguments in your method before varargs:

```java
// foo(13, "foo", "bar", "baz");
// will print:
// 13 - |foo||bar||baz|
public void foo(int a, String... b) {
    System.out.println(a + " - ");

    for (String c : b) {
        System.out.print("|" + c + "|");
    }
}
```

However you can not have arguments of a different type after. These do not work:

```
public void bar(String... b, int b);
public void foo(int a, String... b, int b);
```