# Posting JSON object to HTTP server

Tags: java, android, json

So I'm developing an Android app (Java) that posts a JSON object to a web server. I've achieved this, but I'm battling to get the string value to display properly.
Instead of the server receiving "6666666666666", it receives "Ljava.lang.String;@41108be0]". How on earth do I go about fixing this? Here's my code:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... ID) {
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
Date dateTime = new Date();
string deviceID=null;
try {
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.89:80/");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("IDNo", ID.toString());
json.put("DTSent", dateTime);
json.put("DeviceID", deviceID);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
se.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
request.setEntity(se);
request.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json");
}
```

Please help.

Comment: try `json.put("DTSent", Long.toString(dateTime.getTimeInMillis()));`

Comment: It receives *exactly* what you're sending it. `ID` is an array which does not override `toString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID is a String-Array not just a string. the `...` makes it an array. so either use `ID[0]` or remove the `...` from the function declaration

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in an array of strings (see the three dots?). Try using ID[0] instead.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243145/java-method-with-unlimited-arguments) is a useful post: