# Method with two indeterminate arguments?

Tags: java, methods, variadic-functions

I understand now how to create limitless arguments as per [Java method with unlimited arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243145/java-method-with-unlimited-arguments)

But I was wondering what is the syntax to extend this to two arguments, akin to `printf`?

I want to create unlimited String, int pairs.

The goal would be to display String1 : Int1, String2: Int2 and so on. I'm just not sure what the syntax would be, let alone if it's possible.

Comment: How is your method going to determine how many inputs are strings and how many are integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not directly possible but here are some approaches:

1. If the strings will be unique, you can pass the data as a Map:

   ```
   public void method(Map<String,Integer> pairs) {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. You can use two separate arrays:

   ```
   public void method(String[] strings, int[] ints) {
       if (strings.length != ints.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       ...
   }
   ```

   Call as:

   ```
   method(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
   ```
3. Use `Object` for everything and sort it out later. This suffers from ugly internals and a lack of compile-time type checking but it has the shortest calling syntax:

   ```
   public void method(Object... args) {
       if (args.length % 2 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
           String s = (String)args[i + 0];
           int i = (Integer)args[i + 1];

           ...
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use a builder-style object:

   ```
   public Pairs method() {
       return new Pairs();
   }

   // make the names here meaningful for what your method actually does
   public static class Pairs {
       private static class Pair {
           String s;
           int i;
       }

       private final List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

       private Pairs() {}

       public Pairs add(String s, int i) {
           Pair p = new Pair();
           p.s = s;
           p.i = i;
           pairs.add(p);
           return this;
       }

       public void run() {
           for (Pair p : pairs) {
               ... do method's work here ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Depending on what you want to achieve this might be over-complicating it, but it gives a quite pleasant and fully type-checked syntax for the caller:

   ```
   method()
       .add("a", 1)
       .add("b", 2)
       .add("c", 3)
       .run();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Well, firstly, you can't do this:

```
public void foo(String... strings, int... ints) {
```

Since you'll get an error that the varargs parameter `strings` needs to be the *last* one.

So you'll likely want to make a small wrapper class, say `StringWithInt` and then do like so:

```
public void foo(StringWithInt... values) {
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The invocation of `foo` becomes quite bulky, though: `foo(new StringWithInt("hello", 1), new StringWithInt("world", 2), new StringWithInt("!", 3))`. To me, this is a rather heavy price to pay for static type safety. Of course, others may hold a different opinion on this.

Answer (score 1):

Make the argument one Object argument, which has its own problems...

```
public void foo(Object... things)
```

But probably the best idea is to use a generic list for each argument type :

```
public void foo(List<String> strings, List<Integer> integers) {}
```

If the method specifically requires matchigng pairs a `Map<String, Integer>` could also be used.

(no you can't to original question)

Answer (score 0):

hmmm why don't you just mapping instead?

Something like this

```
public void foo(Map<String,Integer> map){


}
```

Or maybe  instead of String and int, just use objects?

```
 public void foo(Object... args){

 }
```

Comment: Map would only allow two types, and well its nto really a map. Use two generic collecitons instead.

Comment: Yeah, question is kinda vague, but two generic collection would solve things

Comment: @vikingsteve Why the aversion towards that method? I was leaning towards dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: Since using `Object` is generally regarded as bad practise, at least since java 1.5. There is no type safety if someone uses `method("a", 1, "b", 2)` versus `method("a", "b", 1, 2)` -> such errors won't be apparent until run-time (and modern thinking is to catch as many errors at compile-time as possible)