# Simplify the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an if statement like this

```
int val = 1;
if (val == 0 || val == 1 || val == 2 || ...);
```

Is there a way to do it in a more simplified? For example:

```
int val = 1;
if (val == (0 || 1 || 2 || ...));
```

I decided to solve this by creating a function like this:

```
public boolean ifor(int val, int o1, int o2, int o3) {
    return (val == o1 || val == o2 || val == o3);
}
```

But this is not enough, because if I wanted to add another parameter in `ifor`, for example `o4`, I could not do (should I create another function with the new parameter), or if I wanted to reduce the parameters in `o1` and `o2`. I honestly do not know if I explained, if you ask and I'll try to explain.

Comment: Are you saying you need to number of conditions to dynamically change?

Comment: @JesseShellabarger Yes

Comment: @rakeb.void the problem is that is not necessarily a range of values, I might have  `if (val == 1 || val == 5);`

Comment: Then the answer has what you need. He beat me to it :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java method with unlimited arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243145/java-method-with-unlimited-arguments)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generalize the function by using [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) instead:

```
public boolean ifor(int val, int... comparisons){
    for(int o : comparisons){
        if(val == o) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you could call it like any other function, with however many comparisons you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java method with unlimited arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243145/java-method-with-unlimited-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.asList(options).contains(value) // check if int value in int[] array called options
```

Comment: So for example: `int[] options = {6, 0, 2, 3}; int value = 5;`

Comment: `List.contains()` will be O(n). A `Set<Integer>` would be preferable.

Comment: O(n) time (also known as linear time) is like finding a name in your phone book by starting at the beginning and reading down, one-by-one. You have to look at each name in turn. If you've got a long phone book, it will take a long time. Some sets (e.g., HashSet) gives you O(1) time (also known as constant time) for the contains() method. This is like going directly to the name in your phone book, without searching through all the others -- e.g., it's on your favorites page. By the way, you have almost 10K stackoverflow points. Here you are *not* just a high school student.

Comment: @AndyThomas I don't get it.

Comment: Short form: when you put a key in a hash table, its position is computed from the key. When you *look* for a key in a hash table, its position is computed from the key using the same function. You don't have to look at all the other positions. A hash table is a data structure. You have these and many more to look forward to, in classes on data structures and algorithms.

Comment: @AndyThomas Okay, thanks for the help. Wish Java was as simple as Python.

Comment: Python has its own sets, which can also use hashing. These concepts aren't specific to any particular language.

Comment: No I was referring to checking contents and arbitrary arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a enum or Arraylist with valid values and then use the appropriate functions to check for the value.

One such  example using Array List

List list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
...
if (list.contains(3)) { /
  ...
}