# Passing Multiple Numbers in a Parameter for an Array

Tags: java

Is it possible to pass multiple numbers as a parameter for an array parameter? Just like I would with a regular int. Or does the parameter have to be a separate array that I have to create?

public static void main(String[] args)
 {

```
getIntegers(1,2,3,4,5);
```

}

public static void getIntegers(int[] array)
{

//write whatever here

```
}
```

Comment: Hey Aomine-Sorry if this is a duplicate but I looked at that question and it just seemed to confuse me more, as I didn't understand what was being asked.

Comment: here is a better duplicate --> [**Java method with unlimited arguments**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243145/java-method-with-unlimited-arguments). There are many answers to this question and a quick google search would provide a lot of useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use varargs.

```
public static void getIntegers(int... array)
```

It can be referenced as an `int[]` from within the method body.

The method can be invoked by passing any given number of `int`s, or `null`.

**Also note**

- You cannot declare more than one varargs per method signature.
- If you intend to declare more than one parameter in your method, the varargs must be the last one

Comment: Hey Mena! Thanks for your answer, I have not gotten to the varargs chapter yet, so when I saw the "..." i thought it meant "type info here" and wasn't an actual command.